# List of years between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns for a start- and enddate.
My goal is to get a list of each year in that timespan for each row, so

```
+-------------------------+
| startdate  | enddate    |
+------------+------------+
| 2004-08-01 | 2007-01-08 |
| 2005-06-02 | 2007-05-08 |
+------------+------------+
```

should output this:

```
+-------+
| years |
+-------+
| 2004  |
| 2005  |
| 2006  |
| 2007  |
| 2005  |
| 2006  |
| 2007  |
+-------+
```

I have problems now to create the years in between the two dates. My first approach was to use a UNION (order of dates is irrelevant), but the years in between are missing in this case...

```
Select
  Extract(Year From startdate)
From
  table1
Union
Select
  Extract(Year From enddate)
From
  table1
```

Thanks for any advises!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Query

```
; with  CTE as
        (
        select  datepart(year, '2005-12-25') as yr
        union all
        select  yr + 1
        from    CTE
        where   yr < datepart(year, '2013-11-14')
        )
select  yr
from    CTE
```

Comment: Thanks, this one was what I was looking for! In combination with the answer from @lalit-kumar-b.

Comment: This is not Oracle syntax, also `'2013-11-14'` is a string not a date.

Answer (score 3):

***Row Generator technique***

```
SQL> WITH DATA1 AS(
  2  SELECT TO_DATE('2004-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD') STARTDATE, TO_DATE('2007-01-08','YYYY-MM-DD') ENDDATE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT TO_DATE('2005-06-02','YYYY-MM-DD') STARTDATE, TO_DATE('2007-05-08','YYYY-MM-DD') ENDDATE FROM DUAL
  4  ),
  5  DATA2 AS(
  6  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM STARTDATE) ST, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ENDDATE) ED FROM DATA1
  7  ),
  8  data3
  9  AS
 10    (SELECT level-1 line
 11    FROM DUAL
 12      CONNECT BY level <=
 13      (SELECT MAX(ed-st) FROM data2
 14      )
 15    )
 16  SELECT ST+LINE FROM
 17  DATA2, DATA3
 18  WHERE LINE <= ED-ST
 19  ORDER BY 1
 20  /

   ST+LINE
----------
      2004
      2005
      2005
      2006
      2006
      2007

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a table with years as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE tblyears(y int)

INSERT INTO tblyears VALUES (1900);
INSERT INTO tblyears VALUES (1901);
INSERT INTO tblyears VALUES (1902);
```

and so on until

```
INSERT INTO tblyears VALUES (2100)
```

So, you'll write this query:

```
SELECT y.y
FROM tblyears y
JOIN table1 t
ON y.y >= EXTRACT(year from startdate)
AND y.y <= EXTRACT(year from enddate)
ORDER BY y.y
```

[Show SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d006/1/0)